# No uploaded version for any of my modules

Tags: trigger.io

apologies for cluttering up stackoverflow with what is clearly a trigger.io support request.

I've created 2 native modules, and uploaded multiple versions of each. However, when I try to add one of these 'private modules' to one of my trigger.io apps via the Toolkit.app, I get an error 'You cannot activate this module as it has no uploaded versions.' - which is clearly not the case.

anybody have any insight on why this error is happening?

or more to the point are there any trigger.io staff on SO who can get this fixed / or explain to me where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in how we're comparing versions in the 3.3.62 version of the Toolkit - we'll be deploying a new version with a fix later today.

Sorry for the inconvenience!